# A POST request is giving me a 400 Bad Request

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I use angularjs in my project. I am getting a 400 bad request whenever a POST request is made using AttachmentsFactory. POST function of all other factories are working properly. Here's the 
**controller function**
`

```
$scope.updateAttachment = function(attachment){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(attachment));
        var response = AttachmentsFactory.update(attachment); //**here's the problem**
        response.$promise.then(function(data){
            attachment.edit = false;
        })
        /*$http.post("/rest/attachments", attachment).success(function(data){
            //Callback function here.
            //"data" is the response from the server.
        });*/   
    }
```

`
and the Factory **AttachmentsFactory**

```
services.factory('AttachmentsFactory', function ($resource) {
   return $resource('/rest/:eventId/attachments/:fileId', {}, {
       query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
       remove: {method: 'DELETE'},
       update: {method: 'POST', headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}}
   })
});
```

The request is not reaching the server. The object passed as argument is valid : 
`{"name":"ccccc",
  "description":"cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc",
  "fileId":"55144430d18567d9335a94c7",
  "thumbNailId":null,
  "extenstion":"jpg",
  "visibleToPublic":false,
  "edit":true,
  "$$hashKey":"object:565"
 }`

The server function that receives the rest is as follows

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public Result updateEventAttachment(String eventId) {
    try {
        logger.warn("HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE ");
        JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
        Attachment attachment = Json.fromJson(json, Attachment.class);
        logger.debug("Update Request received eventId ={}, fileid{}", eventId, attachment.getFileId());
        Event event = eventService.getEvent(eventId);
        Set<Attachment> attachments = event.getAttachments();
        logger.debug(" Size of attachments = {}", attachments.size());
        attachments.remove(attachment);
        attachments.add(attachment);
        eventService.updateEvent(event);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.warn(" method = deleteEventAttachment exception={}",
                e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ok();
}
```

I added the field `headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}` to the POST method, its not helping. I also tried using $http instead on $resource. Still the same. Tried replacing POST with PUT, still the same.
The GET and DELETE functions of AttachmentsFactory are working properly.
Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? 
Have been stuck with this for more than a day.

Comment: This essentially means that the server is expecting data in a structure that the client is violating. Try removing the $$hashkey key from the client data, which i understand is very much specific to angular and has nothing to do with your server logic.

Comment: @TechMa9iac is correct. Most of the times that I experience this I realize that I failed to create a correct pojo to recieve the object in my Rest layer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. The request is not reaching the server. The server expects a json object. Also, i've added @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) to receiving pojo. It would just ignore unknown fields while building object from JsonNode.

Comment: wonder why I got a vote down

Comment: When you say it doesn't reach the server, can you be more specific? In the Network tab of devtools, does the network request get made? I assume it does and that you are getting a 400 error code in response. In that case, the server must be configured incorrectly, so posting the client code is of no use to us, we need to know the server code instead.

Comment: How does that server code differ from the code for the other POST route handlers? Where is the bit that tells it to accept POST requests? What server framework are you using? I assume it is Java, as well. Correct me if I am wrong. We need all the same information you would need if a coworker came to you asking for help debugging the same problem.

Comment: @ShabinMuhammed, your request body expects a string. You better stringify the whole json object on the client side and then see if things work out. And The request is indeed reaching on the server, otherwise you wouldn't have got 400 as the status code !!

Comment: @TechMa9iac, thanks for opening my eyes. I didn't add the eventId parameter in the call in controller.

Comment: Glad it helped @ShabinMuhammed.. Always remember, as soon as you're receiving a status code other than 0, You're request is definitely reaching Server.. (y)

Comment: @TechMa9iac, I was confused as the server logs didn't show any errors. and assumed it was client side problem. I was 'fundamentally' wrong. Need to add some logs in errors and bad requests handlers.Thank you for the new information.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add a parameter in front end controller  that the server was expecting. Modified the controller as below to solve the issue.

```
$scope.updateAttachment = function(attachment){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(attachment));
    var response = AttachmentsFactory.update({'eventId':$routeParams.id},attachment);
    response.$promise.then(function(data){
        attachment.edit = false;
    })
}
```